# Binding Fails Silently for Nested Property

Tags: wpf, binding, .net-4.0, inotifypropertychanged, targetnullvalue

I am trying to bind a dependency property to an `INotifyPropertyChanged`-enabled property with a multi-level property path.

When the owner object of the property is not `null`, the binding works, but if the owner object is `null`, the binding does not do anything (the converter is not called and [`TargetNullValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not used).

Here is some minimal sample code to reproduce the problem:

---

**Window1.xaml.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace NPCPropertyPath
{
    public abstract class VMBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("e");
            }

            if (PropertyChanged != null) {
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        private class MyConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (value == null) {
                    return null;
                } else if (value is int) {
                    return (((int)value) + 15).ToString();
                } else {
                    return "no int";
                }
            }

            object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }

        private class InnerVM : VMBase
        {
            private int myValue;

            public int MyValue {
                get {
                    return myValue;
                }
                set {
                    if (myValue != value) {
                        myValue = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("MyValue");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private class OuterVM : VMBase
        {
            private InnerVM thing;

            public InnerVM Thing {
                get {
                    return thing;
                }
                set {
                    if (thing != value) {
                        thing = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("Thing");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private readonly OuterVM vm = new OuterVM();

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var txt = new TextBlock();
            txt.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty,
                           new Binding("Thing.MyValue") {
                            Source = vm,
                            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
                            Converter = new MyConverter(),
                            TargetNullValue = "(error)"
                           });
            container.Content = txt;

            var txt2 = new TextBlock();
            txt2.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty,
                            new Binding("Thing") {
                                Source = vm,
                                Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
                                Converter = new MyConverter(),
                                TargetNullValue = "(error)"
                            });
            container2.Content = txt2;
        }

        void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            vm.Thing = new InnerVM();
            vm.Thing.MyValue += 10;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Window1.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="NPCPropertyPath.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="NPCPropertyPath" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Change value" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <ContentControl Name="container"/>
        <ContentControl Name="container2"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

*Of course, this is a significantly simplified form of my real application, where there is quite a bit more going on and the involved classes are not crammed together in two files (or even in the same assembly) where they can all see each other.*

This sample displays a window with a button and two content controls. Each of the content controls contains a [`TextBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) whose [`Text` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is bound to a property from a view-model. The view-model instance (of type `OuterVM`) is assigned to the [`Source` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of each binding.

`OuterVM` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`; it has a property `Thing` of type `InnerVM` (which also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`), which in turn has a property `MyValue`.

The first text block is bound to `Thing.MyValue`, the second one just to `Thing`. Both of the bindings have a converter set, as well as a value for the `TargetNullValue` property that should be displayed on the text block if the target property is `null`.

The `Thing` property of the `OuterVM` instance is initially `null`. When clicking the button, something is assigned to that property.

**The problem:** Only the second text block displays anything initially. The one that is bound to `Thing.MyValue` neither invokes the converter (as evidenced by setting breakpoints), nor does it use the value of the `TargetNullValue` property.

**Why? And how can I have the first text block display a default value instead of `Thing.MyValue` while `Thing` is not assigned?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this purpose you should not use `TargetNullValue`, you should use [`FallbackValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  property of the `Binding`.

Comment: Fascinating find! Who'd think of looking in the docs for an additional `FallbackValue` property after having found the `TargetNullValue` property already? :)